# jQuery - equivalent to each(), but for a single element

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

What's the jQuery equivalent for each():

```
$(".element").each(function(){  
  // do stuff
});
```

when attaching a function to a single element, like `#element` ?

Comment: Is there a reason why using each wouldn't work?

Comment: You're really getting into it no? But what do you mean exactly? I don't think I understand the question.

Comment: it works, but it feels wrong using it like this :)

Comment: are you wanting to bind some mouse event to it or something?

Comment: `each` should be used when you need to distinguish between elements for example you have 10 buttons and upon click you want to alert the clicked button ID or text. Otherwise just omit the `each` and the function will be applied to all elements.

Comment: They should allow to pass function into `.first()`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can always reference the jQuery object in a variable:

```
var $el = $('#element');
```

...then manipulate it.

```
$el.doSomething();          // call some jQuery methods from the cached object
$el.doSomethingElse();
```

If the reason you wanted `.each()` was to reference the DOM element as `this`, you don't really need the `this` keyword to do it, you can simply grab the DOM element out of the jQuery object.

```
var element = $('#element')[0];       // both of these give you the DOM element
var element = $('#element').get(0);   //        at index 0
```

The two of these are equivalent, and will retrieve the DOM element that would be referenced as `this` in the `.each()`.

```
alert( element.tagName );  // alert the tagName property of the DOM element
alert( element.id );       // alert the ID property of the DOM element
```

---

I'd note that it isn't necessarily bad to use each to iterate over a single element.

The benefits are that you have easy access to the DOM element, and you can do so in a new scope so you don't clutter the surrounding namespace with variables.

There are other ways to accomplish this as well. Take this example:

```
(function( $ ) {

    // Inside here, "this" will refer to the DOM element,
    //    and the "$" parameter, will reference the jQuery library.

    alert( this.tagName );

    // Any variables you create inside will not pollute the surrounding 
    //     namespace.

    var someVariable = 'somevalue'; // is local to this function

}).call( $('#element')[0], jQuery );
```

Comment: `$('#element')[0] != $('#element').get(0)` The former returns the DOM element, the latter returns a jQuery map object of the DOM element. You could call `$('#element').get(0).click(function...);` whereas `$('#element')[0].click(function...);` would be invalid.

Comment: The safety net the each provides is that it won't call the callack when the jQuery object doesn't exist thus saving in checking for jquery object  explicitly.

Answer (score 14):

To directly answer your question, `.each()` operates normally on element sets of any size including 1.

You can also omit the `.each()` call completely and just call jQuery methods on `$('#element')`. Remember that you can chain most if not all jQuery method calls as they return the jQuery object. This even works on multiple elements for the matter, depending on what the methods do.

```
$('#element').doSomething().doSomethingElse();
```

If you need to reference the object multiple times, make a variable:

```
var $elm = $('#element');
$elm.doSomething();
doSomethingElse($elm);
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `first()`.

`each()` matches all elements, while `first()` matches only the first.

There are other selectors too. When you use the id in the selector, you will only get one element. This is the main difference between `.element` and `#element`. The first is a class that can be assigned to many elements, while the second is an id that belongs to only (at most) one element.

You can still use each if only one (or 0) element is returned. Also, you can skip each altogether if you want to link an event. You use `each` when you want to execute a specific function for each element in the list of elements.

Comment: Thank You!  I came here looking for this.  All the other answers seem to unnecessarily add the function into an extension method.

Answer (score 2):

If there is only 1 element, you can access it normally using the selector.

```
$('#your_element').your_event(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Behind the scenes, `each` is just a `for` loop that iterates through each element in the `map` returned by `jQuery`.

It is essentially<sup>†</sup> the same as:

```
var i, map = $('...selector...');
for (i = 0; i < map.length; i++)
{
  someFunction(i, map[i]);
}
```

† There's more to it than this, involving calling the function in the context of the map element etc.

It's implementation is to provide a convenient way to call a function on `each` element in the selection.

Comment: It's actually `someFunction.call(map[i], i, map[i])` or `someFunction.apply(map[i], [ i, map[i] ])`. Just to be nitpicky.

Comment: @btleffler, yes hence the "† There's more to it than this". The reason i didn't use those particular abstractions was for the sake of brevity and readability.

Comment: Ha! Don't know how I missed that one. It was right there the whole time. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like $('#element').children().each()
supposing you have something like a ul with an id and you want the li each inside it?

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to call a (non-jQuery) function in a new scope I think using "each" still is a valid (and probably the most elegant) way and it stays true to the jQuery syntax although I agree to Alex, it feels wrong since it might have some overhead.
If you can change the syntax use `$('#element')[0]` as replacement for `this` (as already mentioned in the accepted answer).

Btw could someone with enough reputation please correct the comment of "zzzzBov" about the accepted answer? 
`$('#element')[0]` and `$('#element').get(0)` **ARE!** the same, if you want the jQuery object use `$('#element').first()` or `$('#element').eq(0)`