# How to run function on first object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this function which runs for each instance of 'fullName':

```
$(xml).find("fullName").each(function(){ ... });
```

But there is really only ever one instance and I don't want to be using each, is there some other way to create this function without using each. Maybe just:

```
$(xml).find("fullName").it(function(){ ... });
```

Comment: Yes, use `first()`, or explain what function it is, and there might be a suitable jQuery method to use.

Comment: I mean, the function is rather unique, but does jQuery have a method for setting/ getting cookies?

Comment: This has been discussed here: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856938/jquery-equivalent-to-each-but-for-a-single-element**.

Comment: Not without a plugin, I think, no.

Comment: It might depend on what the Function is meant to be used for.. Ex: Do you wanna use a Simpe function expression or a whole function declaration... There might be several alternatives to achieving what you want.... Just try to Explain further

Comment: @ErickBest Well, I get a cookie, compare it to stuff, set a cookie, set some html, and redirect the window.location in some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just reference by index:

```
$(xml).find("fullName")[0]
```

Comment: But where is the function?

Comment: @Watson As the value you wish to use is directly accessible there is no need for a function. Of course, you could use a function if you liked. This is described by LimH's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this

```
var func = function(){ ... }
func.call($(xml).find("fullName")[0], args));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the .first() method

http://api.jquery.com/first/

Comment: But how does that help the OP run a function? That just returns another jQuery object and he or she already has a jQuery object...

Answer (score 1):

```
var fnc = null;
if (typeof (fnc = $(xml).find("fullName").eq(0)) == 'function'){
    fnc(args);
}
```

Comment: But how does that help the OP run a function? That just returns another jQuery object and he or she already has a jQuery object...

Comment: @nnnnnn, add .call(arguments)

Comment: So _that's_ what your answer should say. With more detail. (Assuming it doesn't then become a duplicate of Lim H.'s answer.) But you don't need `.eq(0)` since the OP is confident that the `.find()` will only find one item anyway - that's the point of the question...

Comment: @nnnnnn, I used to not trust the customer's data. Answer corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Or....

```
$(xml).find("fullName").first()
```

Comment: But (as I already asked about some other answers) how does that help the OP run a function? That just returns another jQuery object and he or she already has a jQuery object...

Answer (score 0):

What of:

```
(function($){
 $.fn.anotherFunction=function(){

alert('Handles for anotherFunction');
}
})(jQuery)
```

and call it like::

```
$(xml).find("fullName").anotherFunction();
```

is that what He Wants??